# Navigate an element through its nodes' names in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, nodes

I've got an XML like this

```
[...]
<element>
  <nodeA></nodeA>
  <nodeB></nodeB>
</element>

<element>
  <nodeC></nodeC>
  <nodeA></nodeA>
</element>
[...]
```

As you can see, the nodes aren't required and they can appear in different orders so I can't access them through their index as childs of the element. I know I could use a loop to check element's child nodes' name and then a switch to save them but I'd like to know if there's a simplier way for achieving this as I have tons of elements and it would take a while to check all of their child nodes. I can't use a custom object either as I have to pass all the nodes' content as an ordered array to a generic function.

If you need to know something else, let me know. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
I'm making an array of five objects consisting of the elements five child nodes. I've got to set default values for the ones missing too. Child nodes will never have children. The most complex element would be:

```
<element>
  <nodeA></nodeA>
  <nodeB></nodeB>
  <nodeC></nodeC>
  <nodeD></nodeD>
  <nodeE></nodeE>
</element>
```

Comment: *"I have tons of elements and it would take a while to check all of their child nodes"* - I'm pretty sure it wouldn't. Have you tried?  (Also you are not specific enough about your XML and what nodes you want to select. All named `nodeA`? The first one? Can there be more than one node named `nodeA`? Can they have descendants?)

Comment: @Tomalak I'm making an array of five objects consisting of the elements five child nodes. I've got to set default values for the ones missing too. And about the child nodes they will never hace children. The more complex element would be:

`<element>
  <nodeA></nodeA>
  <nodeB></nodeB>
  <nodeC></nodeC>
  <nodeD></nodeD>
  <nodeE></nodeE>
</element>`

Comment: In this situation you can safely call `element[i].getElementsByTagName('nodeA')` and either that gives you something or not, if that node does not exist. I would not write a solution that depends on the position/index of the child.

Comment: In any case you would probably have to show some code, that's always better than paragraphs full of text descriptions.

Comment: That'd be unnecessary. I got it to work exactly the way I wanted it to with `xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName('element')[index].getElementsByTagName(nodeName)[0]`. I'll post the piece of code in the main post. Thanks so much @Tomalak. I'd like you to choose your solution but I'm afraid I can't with my current reputation.

Comment: Since I have not posted an answer yet (for lack of a solid definition of the problem - always post code along with your question!), there is nothing you could vote on/accept anyway :) I'd suggest you pick "answer my own question" and post your solution there. Answering your own questions is perfectly fine here. (I'll up-vote and get you over the first reputation hurdle this way.)

Comment: It doesn't feel right to take merit for what you've done but I guess I'll do 8 hours from now as I'm not able right now again because of my lack of reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved thanks to @Tomalak. Here's the resulting code:

```
var xmlDocument = loadXMLDocument("xml_file.xml");

function xmlReadAttribute(attributeName, index) {
    var attribute = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName('Series')[index].getElementsByTagName(attributeName)[0];
    if (attribute !== undefined) return attribute.textContent;
    return '';
}
```

Comment: That's maybe a little better: http://pastebin.com/zCu1JgCW if you want to fetch all attributes in one go.